# Allow SSRS table cell to overflow into next cell (ala Excel)

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2008, bids

In MS-Excel, if the text in a cell is too long for the cell, and the next cell to its right is empty, the text will spill into that neighbor cell.

Is there any way to replicate this behavior in SSRS/ BIDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think this is possible.

Closest you can get is using the [merged cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630416%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) feature, or just exporting to Excel and relying on Microsoft Excel to render it that way for you.

Note that the feature in Excel only *visually* "spills" the text into the next cell, it's not actually *in* that cell.

Comment: The problem with merged cells, is it seems to be "global."  I only want this to happen *if* the text is too long and *if* the cell to the right is empty.

Comment: I understand, that's one reason I said "closest you'll get". What you want isn't possible in renderers apart from Excel.

Comment: Fair enough.  My temp. workaround is `Left(Feilds!myValue.Value, XX)` until a better idea comes along.